# Object reference not set to an instance of an object using combobox.selecteditem.tostring();

Tags: c#, string, file-io, combobox

I'm trying to replace certain lines of text in my .text file but am getting the error specified above. Please help, I don't know what the error means and have looked everywhere to try to find a way to solve this problem. Nothing has really made sense to me, thanks in advance! If you need any other info,  please ask instead of just setting my post to off-topic, I really don't get what that means either.

Current Code:

```
    private void DeleteButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Contact.");
        }
        else
        {

            comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
            string currentselection = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
            File.WriteAllLines(currentselection + ".txt",       File.ReadAllLines(currentselection + ".txt").Select(line => line.Replace(currentselection, "")));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line is causing the exception?

Comment: `comboBox2.SelectedItem` is null ofcourse.

Comment: @RohitVats That's what I don't understand, why is `comboBox2.SelectedItem` null when during the program I set it to something?

Comment: If you put a break point on it, what does comboBox2.SelectedItem equal ? as you are removing the selectedItem from comboBox (first remove) it should be null when you read from it

Comment: Either its null before entering into method OR becomes null after this line - `comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedItem);` since you remove the selectedItem from the ItemSource which automatically set the SelectedItem to be null. Isn't it?

Comment: First removed the selected item, try rem'ing it out and see what happends (I expect the remove, sets it to null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this . put a break point under this line.

comboBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox2.SelectedItem); - first one

Watch how the checkbox2.items change and the seletItem is null.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand what I did now! Will set as answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

You get **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** when trying to access something that is null. In your case, `comboBox2.SelectedItem` appears to be null. You'll need to check for that before accessing it. Doing `== ""` is not the same thing!

Change your:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == "")
```

To:

```
if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == null)
```

Also, you'll notice that once you have deleted the item - trying to access it with `SelectedItem` won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It means `SelectedItem` is null.  `SelectedItem` will be null if nothing is selected in the combobox.

A NullReference exception always means you are trying to access a member on a value that is null.  You should use a debugger and check all the variables when that error occurs.